# Three.js - show texture map on part of object

Tags: javascript, three.js, textures

whats the easiest way to show texture on center / right/left side of an 2d object?

i have tried to play with the offset and repeat of the texture but had no luck, and i cant find answer for it anywhere.

plus, i have tried this:

```
        someButton.onClick(function () {

            var geom = editor.selected.geometry;
            var uvs = geom.faceVertexUvs[0]; 

            var face0 = uvs[0];
            face0[0] = new THREE.Vector2(0,1);
            face0[1] = new THREE.Vector2(0,0.2);
            face0[2] = new THREE.Vector2(0.5,1);

            var face1 = uvs[1];
            face1[0] = new THREE.Vector2(0,0.2);
            face1[1] = new THREE.Vector2(0.5,0.2);
            face1[2] = new THREE.Vector2(0.5,1);

            geom.uvsNeedUpdate = true;

    });
```

again, no luck.

for example, if the object is a 2d square and i want the koala bear picture to be centered, its need to look like this :

[koala bear on center of square](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TCzFX.jpg)

i want to change the position of texture dynamically
thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show some of your code attempts?

Comment: Try `face0[0].set( u, v );` Do not instantiate a new instance.

Answer (score 0):

I finally came up with a nice solution, take a look if it helps:

```
someButton.onClick(function () {

    var obj = editor.selected;
    var width = obj.geometry.parameters.width;
    var height = obj.geometry.parameters.height;
    var geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(width,height, 3, 3);
    var material = obj.material;

    material.map.wrapS = material.map.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
    material.map.repeat.x = material.map.repeat.y = 3;

    var materials = [];
    materials.push(material);
    materials.push(new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({}));

    for (var i = 0; i < 18; i++) {
        if (i == 8 || i == 9) geomtery.faces[i].materialIndex = 0;
        else geomtery.faces[i].materialIndex = 1;
    }

    obj.geomtery = geomtery;
    obj.material = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materials);
    editor.signals.materialChanged.dispatch(obj);

});
```